# ¿Como hago un corrimiento de colores de azul a verde en matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, color

Estoy haciendo un programa para graficar 22 lineas distintas pero no logro hacer que el corrimiento de colores sea paulatino de azul a verde para que se vea de mejor manera la diferencia en el crecimiento entre cada una de la lineas en lugar de un color random. Por favor ayuda

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t1 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.02)
for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]:
    plt.plot(t1, t1*n)
plt.show()
```

[image: Imagen de colores random]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es [crear un mapa de colores propio](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html). Esto es especialmente útil cuando queremos mapas de colores más complejos, similares a los que [trae Matplotilib por defecto](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html), así mismo, el planteamiento que vamos a ver a continuación se puede usar con cualquier mapa de colores predefinido por Matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, Normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Diccionario para definir cada canal y como cambian en el rango 0-1
## se puede agregar el canal alpha si se desea.
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),   
                 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

        'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

        'blue':  ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                  (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }

# Creamos nuestro mapa de colores personalizado
blue_green = LinearSegmentedColormap('BlueGreen', cdict, N=100)

# Datos
t1 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.02)
vals = np.arange(1, 21)

# La instancia de color.Normalize es un callable que
## permite normalizar cualquier valor entre  min y max 
norm = Normalize(vals.min(), vals.max())  # Normalize(min(vals), max(vals)) en lista

for n in vals:
    plt.plot(t1, t1*n, color=blue_green(norm(n)))


plt.show()
```

El mapa en este caso es bastante simple dónde la cantidad de azul y verde aumentan y descienden linealmente todo el tiempo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier mapa de colores creados vía `LinearSegmentedColormap` permite obtener un color concreto pesándola un valor entre 0 y 1. La función de `color.Normalize` es normalizar nuestros valores a este rango.

Para usar un mapa de los predefinidos en Matplotlib solo tenemos que cargarlo usando su nombre, por ejemplo:

```
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu')
norm = Normalize(vals.min(), vals.max())

for n in vals:
    plt.plot(t1, t1*n, color=cmap(norm(n)))
```

El mapa puede ser reutilizado en gráficas posteriores si lo necesitamos.

La salida para este ejemplo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Con muy pocos cambios puedes resolverlo, veamos:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t1 = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.02)

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
lista_normalizada = [ (n-min(lista))/(max(lista)-min(lista)) for n in lista]

for i,n in enumerate(lista):
    print(i)
    plt.plot(t1, t1*n, color=[0.1, lista_normalizada[21-i], lista_normalizada[i]])

plt.show()
```

Como verás, el principal cambio es el uso del parámetro `color` en `plt.plot()`, el cual lo indicamos como una lista con los valores rojo, verde y azul. Para lograr el gradiente hay que ir modificando los componente verde y azul. Como estos valores se ajustan de 0 a 1, necesitamos una lista normalizada (`lista_normalizada`) que calculamos para que los valores originales se correspondan con valores de 0 a 1. Luego simplemente vamos decreciendo el componente azul y aumentando el verde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]